# Regex in AR query using end of string char (/z) returns empty AR relation; returns expected results using end-of-line ($) [PG]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, postgresql, activerecord

NOTE:  The following uses a PG database.

I have setup wherein model Foo belongs to model Bar.  In trying to return all entries Foo in which bar.name ends with "abc" (e.g. "def abc" but not "def abc-2"), I wrote the query:

```
Foo.joins(:bar).where('bar.name ~* ?', "abc\z")
```

This query returns no results.  However, this query:

```
Foo.joins(:bar).where('bar.name ~* ?', "abc$")
```

returns the results I expected.

Digging a little deeper, I tested the same queries, but omitting the "abc" (i.e. querying solely on the regex anchors).  For my current database, the "\z" query returns 94 results, whereas the "$" query returns 2,016 results.

I'd like to understand (a) if I've done something fundamentally wrong with my query, and (b) what's going on under the hood that leads to this behavior.  It seems like the database is being queried like a bunch of chunked multi-line strings rather than each entry field being considered its own string, but I don't know why, or even if that's the case.

Comment: Why are you not using `\Z`?  `\z` is not valid in PG regex.  Also, do you need to escape the `\ ` character?

Comment: I think that's it... I'd tried both \z and \Z, which returned identical results.  After testing \\Z, it looks like I had to escape the special character, which I didn't realize.  Thanks!